# Xamarin.iOS handle push notification when app is not closed

Tags: c#, push-notification, xamarin.ios

I managed to handle push notification if the app is in the background using the method `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. Is there a way to handle the push notification if the app is in the foreground and not closed ? Thanks

Comment: Check out my answer here that answered recently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255637/1134836

Answer (score 3):

Have you implemented [UserNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications)? If you deploy your project on iOS 10+ you can try to subscribe the notification in the `FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)` like:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
{
    var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
        Console.WriteLine(granted);
    });
    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new MyNotificationCenterDelegate();
}
```

Then when the notification comes and the application is in the foreground, the `WillPresentNotification()` will fire, this handle event returns which action will this app response when notification comes. At last you can get the userInfo in the `DidReceiveNotificationResponse()` event:

```
public class MyNotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    public override void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler();
    }

    public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);

    }       
}
```

But if you don't want to implement `UserNotification` or you just push a silent remote notification with the key `content-available` true, the `didReceiveRemoteNotification()` will also be fired even though the app is in foreground.

Comment: I did already subscribe the notification, but I can't find the `WillPresentNotification()` method and when I added them I had the same problem.

Comment: I modify the weakDelegate to strong delegate. Also if you both subscribe the `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` and `ReceivedRemoteNotification` events. `ReceivedRemoteNotification` will never be fired, read the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplicationDelegate.ReceivedRemoteNotification/p/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary/) you will find this api deprecated on ios 10+.

Comment: Still the same issue, receiving a notification does not trigger those methods and the only method that triggers is `DidReceiveRemoteNotification ` only when the app is in the background .. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: It's weird. Which third party library are you using and which ios version are you using?

Comment: ios 11.2 and not using a third party lib for notifications.

Answer (score 1):

To handle the push notification event regardless the app run in foreground or background. Following these steps to get DidReceiveRemoteNotification be called always

1) Override DidReceiveRemoteNotification method in AppDelegate.cs

```
public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
```

2) Add Required background modes -  remote-notification(value) to info.plist

3) Set content-available in payload to 1

```
{
"aps" : {
    "alert" : {
        "title" : "Game Request",
        "body" : "Bob wants to play poker"
    },
    "badge" : 5,
    "content-available" : 1
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The override method `ReceivedRemoteNotification` or `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` in the `AppDelegate`, will get fired when you receive the push notification when you are in foreground.

In this method you can check if your app is in `Active` state or not and based on it, you can handle your notifications.

```
if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Active) 
{
    //You app is in Foreground state.
    //Process the Pushnotification data, or show alert.
}
```

[Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623117-application).

> Implement the
>   application(*:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)
>   method instead of this one whenever possible. If your delegate
>   implements both methods, the app object calls the
>   application(*:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)
>   method.

So, if you have both methods (`ReceivedRemoteNotification` & `DidReceiveRemoteNotification`) implemented in your AppDelegate, then `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` method will get called.

Comment: Sadly `ReceivedRemoteNotification` did not trigger once I received a notification in the foreground. Here's my code:

`public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
        {
            var userInfo1 = userInfo;
        }

        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            var value = userInfo;
}`
The second method is called properly when app in background, the first doesn't trigger at all.

Comment: As per apple's doc, DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler) triggers when app is either in background or foreground. Have you tried adding the above condition in this method?

Comment: Yes I did add the condition for checking the app state but still no success.

Comment: Does it go inside that if block? Apple do not show Push notification anywhere when your app is in Foreground. You have to manually handle it like showing the alert from the app inside this condition. What actually you think, should be done in case app is in Foreground?

Comment: It does not enter the block at all, but it does only if the app is in the background. What should be done is in case the app in the foreground I can manage to show alert and later if the user in the foreground and clicks the notification it should redirect him, that I did manage to do if app in the background using the `DidReceiveRemoteNotification `.

Comment: Can you try "if (application.ApplicationState == UIApplicationState.Active)" instead of UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationState

Comment: Sorry but it's the same thing, does not enter the block or check unless the app is closed and open it all over again.

Comment: Are you testing this scenario like your app is Active on Foreground, and you are receiving a push notification from somewhere while still being in Foreground? Make sure while this testing your app is in Front most and not in the background and check what happens when you receive the push notification. It should surely go into this method as well as in this if block.

Answer (score 0):

I got both foreground and background notifications in Xamarin iOS by the sample app.delegte.cs code shown below.

```
   using Foundation;
   using System;
   using System.Diagnostics;
   using System.Linq;
   using UIKit;
   using UserNotifications;
   using WindowsAzure.Messaging;
   using Firebase.Core;
   using Firebase.CloudMessaging;
   using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
   using ObjCRuntime;

   namespace NotificationHubSample.iOS
```

{
[Register("AppDelegate")]

```
   public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    private SBNotificationHub Hub { get; set; }
    

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        

        base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);

        Firebase.Core.App.Configure();

        RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.BackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum);


        return true;
    }

    void RegisterForRemoteNotifications()
    {
        // register for remote notifications based on system version
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {
            
            

            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert |
                UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound |
                UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
                (granted, error) =>
                {
                    if (granted)
                        InvokeOnMainThread(UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications);
                });
        }
        else if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
        {
            var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
            UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
            new NSSet());

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
        }
        else
        {
            UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
        }
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
    }

    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        Hub = new SBNotificationHub(AppConstants.ListenConnectionString, AppConstants.NotificationHubName);

        // update registration with Azure Notification Hub
        Hub.UnregisterAll(deviceToken, (error) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to call unregister {error}");
                return;
            }

            var tags = new NSSet(AppConstants.SubscriptionTags.ToArray());
            Hub.RegisterNative(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) =>
            {
                if (errorCallback != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"RegisterNativeAsync error: {errorCallback}");
                }
            });

            var templateExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(120).ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
            Hub.RegisterTemplate(deviceToken, "defaultTemplate", AppConstants.APNTemplateBody, templateExpiration, tags, (errorCallback) =>
            {
                if (errorCallback != null)
                {
                    if (errorCallback != null)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"RegisterTemplateAsync error: {errorCallback}");
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        // Firebase ios Registration
        Messaging.SharedInstance.ApnsToken = deviceToken;
        
       }
   // Process the notification when the app is open.
   
public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        ProcessNotification(userInfo, false);
        

    }   // End of the ReceiveRemoteNotification method

    

    // Process the notification when the app is closed.
    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        ProcessNotification(userInfo, false);            
        
    }


    void ProcessNotification(NSDictionary options, bool fromFinishedLaunching)
    {
        // make sure we have a payload
        if (options != null && options.ContainsKey(new NSString("aps")))
        {
            // get the APS dictionary and extract message payload. Message JSON will be converted
            // into a NSDictionary so more complex payloads may require more processing
            NSDictionary aps = options.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;
            
            string payload = string.Empty;
            NSString payloadKey = new NSString("alert");
            
            if (aps.ContainsKey(payloadKey))
            {
                payload = aps[payloadKey].ToString();
            }

          
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(payload))
            {
                (App.Current.MainPage as MainPage)?.AddMessage(payload);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Received request to process notification but there was no payload.");
        } 
     } // End of the ProcessNotification method





}
```

}