# Xamarin - iOS: Why do I not receive push notifications with app in foreground through NotificationServiceExtension?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, unnotificationserviceextension

Push notifications that goes through the extension are always received when app is killed, I can notice that on the device e through the logs printed by the extension. When app is in foreground, nothing happens, neither I see logs in the extension or in the WillPresentNotification method in the AppDelegate (method that works perfectly in foreground with "normal" push that do not need to be intercepted by the extension).
I tried also to add the method ReceivedRemoteNotification(...), neither this method was called as I've seen from the logs.

I use a UNNotificationServiceExtension to map the content of the notification.

```
[Register("NotificationService")]

public class NotificationService : UNNotificationServiceExtension
{
    Action<UNNotificationContent> ContentHandler { get; set; }
    UNMutableNotificationContent BestAttemptContent { get; set; }

    .
    .
    .

    protected NotificationService(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }

    public override void DidReceiveNotificationRequest(UNNotificationRequest request,
                                                       Action<UNNotificationContent> contentHandler)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NOTIFICATIONS: NotificationExtension: entered DidReceive");

        ContentHandler = contentHandler;
        BestAttemptContent = (UNMutableNotificationContent)request.Content.MutableCopy();

        // Mapping of body and title

        ContentHandler(BestAttemptContent);
    }


    public override void TimeWillExpire()
    {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.

        Console.WriteLine("NOTIFICATIONS: NotificationExtension: entered TimeWillExpire");

        ContentHandler(BestAttemptContent);
    }
}
```

In the AppDelegate I have the code to show the notification in foreground:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : FormsApplicationDelegate,
                                   IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate,
                                   IUIAlertViewDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        LogBroker.Instance.TraceDebug("START");
        
        .
        .
        .
        
        LogBroker.Instance.TraceDebug("RegisterForNotifications: Register For Push Notification");
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(
            UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
            (approved, err) => {

                if (err != null)
                {
                    LogBroker.Instance.TraceError($"RegisterForNotifications: {err.LocalizedDescription}");
                    return;
                }

                if (approved)
                {
                    InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        LogBroker.Instance.TraceDebug("RegisterForNotifications: Approved");
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    LogBroker.Instance.TraceWarning($"RegisterForNotifications: Rejected by user!");
                }

            });

        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

        LoadApplication(new App());
        
        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, launchOptions);
    }

    .
    .
    .

    [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter _, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        LogBroker.Instance.TraceDebug($"NOTIFICATIONS: entered WillPresentNotification");

        var pushType = notification.Request.Content.UserInfo?.ValueForKey(new NSString("push-type"))?
                                   .ToString() ?? "";

        LogBroker.Instance.TraceDebug($"NOTIFICATIONS: push type - {pushType}");

        if (pushType == "call")
        {
            completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.None);
        }
        else
        {
            LogBroker.Instance.TraceDebug($"NOTIFICATIONS: show push notification");
            completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert |
                              UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound);
        }
    }
}
```

The payload of the notifications is something like this:

```
{
aps =     {
    alert =         {
        "loc-args" =             (
            "***"
        );
        "loc-key" = "IM_MSG";
    };
    badge = 1;
    "mutable-content" = 1;
    sound = "msg.caf";
};
"call-id" = 909d32775168c0db;
"domain-name" = "***";
panda = blue;
"pn_ttl" = 30;
"push-services" = vdes;
"push-type" = message;
"text-message" = "DND;ON";
```

}

Comment: Try to add "  "mutable-content"=1" in aps={....}

Comment: Thank you Adrain but it is present yet

Comment: Did you request for notification permission?

Comment: Yes, and user approved

Comment: How about plist setting? Did you created Notification service extension?

Comment: Yes, I think I've created all as by guideline, cause the extension works perfectly when app is killed

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684355/xamarin-ios-handle-push-notification-when-app-is-not-closed

Comment: Checked but I didn't found anything helpful in respect to what I've just tried. I thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: You are welcome :) you can try the official sample project to see if it's work.https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/main/ios10/MonkeyNotify/MonkeyNotify/Classes/UserNotificationCenterDelegate.cs

Comment: Thank you so much Adrain, I will try it!